# Bounding A sequence of Measurable Functions (Rudin's RCA Prob. 1.7)

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, measure-theory

> Suppose that $\mu$ is a positive measure on $X$, $f : X \to [0,\infty]$ is measurable, $\int_X f d \mu = c \in (0,\infty)$, and $\alpha$ is a constant. Prove that
>
> $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_X n \ln [1 + (f/n)^\alpha] = \begin{cases} \infty, & \mbox{if } 0 < \alpha < 1 \\ c, & \mbox{if }  \alpha = 1 \\ 0, & \mbox{if }  1 < \alpha < \infty \end{cases}$$
>
> Hint: If $\alpha \ge 1$, the integrands are dominated by $\alpha f$. If $\alpha < 1$, Fatou's lemma can be applied.

I already dealt with the $\alpha < 1$ case. I am having trouble showing that $|f_n| \le \alpha f$ for all $n \in \Bbb{N}$, so that I can apply Lebesgue's Dominating Convergence theorem to prove that I could use some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(t)=(1+t)^{\alpha} - 1-t^{\alpha}$. Then $f(0)=0$ and $f'(t)=\alpha (1+t)^{\alpha -1}-\alpha t^{\alpha -1}$. Since $1+t >t$ and $\alpha \geq 1$ we see that $f'(t) \geq 0$. Hence f is increasing, so $f(t) \geq f(0)=0$. Now $1+t <e^{t}$ implies $(1+t)^{\alpha} <e^{\alpha t}$ so $1+t^{\alpha} \leq (1+t)^{\alpha}<e^{{\alpha} t}$. Put $t=\frac f n$ and take logarithms

Answer (score 2):

If $t>0$ the Mean Value Theorem shows that $\log(1+t)\le t$. Something somehow shows that $1+t^\alpha\le(1+t)^\alpha$.